# How to create individual pricing for products per Customer?

Tags: database, ms-access

I am setting up a Database to be used for Invoicing orders. we have different jobs with different pricing for our products. When I enter in a new job I would like it to link to our default pricing and be able to modify it for only that customer. We have over 100 products and only certain ones get modified pricing per job hence the default being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a m to n relation between customers and products, realized by a junction table holding the customer specific price. Assuming that you have a Table `Customer` with a `CustomerID` as primary key and a table `Product` with a `ProductID` as primary key, the new table looks like this:

```
Table CustomerPrice
-------------------
CustomerID  Number/Long, no default value, required
ProductID   Number/Long, no default value, required
Price       Number/Decimal, Scale 2, no default value, required
```

The primary key must be a compound key (`CustomerID`, `ProductID`). This ensures that there can be only one customer specific price per product.

Add relations between `Customer.CustomerID` and `CustomerPrice.CustomerID` with delete cascade and between `Product.ProductID` and `CustomerPrice.ProductID` with delete cascade. (You can do all that in the UI.)

The default Price would be stored directly in the `Product` table.

You can select a product price like this

```sql
SELECT x.CustomerID, x.CustomerName, x.ProductID, x.ProductName, Nz(cp.Price, x.Price) AS Price
FROM
    (SELECT c.CustomerID, c.Name AS CustomerName, p.ProductID, p.Name AS ProductName, p.Price
     FROM Customer c, Product p) x
    LEFT JOIN CustomerPrice AS cp ON x.ProductID = cp.ProductID AND x.CustomerID = cp.CustomerID;
```

This yields the customer specific price when available and the default product price otherwise.

If you need the data for a specific customer or product, add a WHERE clause to the nested SELECT

```sql
SELECT x.CustomerID, x.CustomerName, x.ProductID, x.ProductName, Nz(cp.Price, x.Price) AS Price
FROM
    (SELECT c.CustomerID, c.Name AS CustomerName, p.ProductID, p.Name AS ProductName, p.Price
     FROM Customer c, Product p
     WHERE c.CustomerID = 7 AND p.ProductID = 10) x
    LEFT JOIN CustomerPrice AS cp ON x.ProductID = cp.ProductID AND x.CustomerID = cp.CustomerID;
```